# Join in data tables (Warning message: In `[.data.table`(dt[dt2 on = .(common_key), : Item 1 of j's result for group 8 is zero length)

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables --

```
 1) dt
       id       week       group 
    1: QQQ 2012-01-16    A
    2: QQW 2012-01-16    A
    3: QQW 2012-01-16    B
    4: QQD 2012-01-16    A
    5: ASE 2012-01-16    D
   ---                                           
 99999: RLN 2012-01-30    C
100000: PLF 2012-01-23    E
100001: PNI 2012-01-23    A
100002: RLF 2012-01-23    A
100003: PEV 2012-02-06    A

2) dt2

          id    other_id yet_another_id week_group     attribute  other_attribute yet_another_attribute   attribute_again
     1:  QQQ     KFG     234           2012-01-09     2012-01-09        there           this         (Missing)
     2:  QQW     FKI     534           2012-01-09     2012-01-16        there           this         (Missing)
     3:  QEW     LRN     231           2012-01-09     2012-01-23        there           this         (Missing)
     4:  SAE     UNJ     123           2012-01-09     2012-01-30         here           this         (Missing)
     5:  DWT     KJY     123           2012-01-09     2012-02-06         here           that         (Missing)
    ---                                                                                                                
682910:  SEC     URM     123           2012-01-23     2012-04-02        here            this         (Missing)
682911:  FTW     JUP     234           2014-07-14     2014-07-14        there           this            Burger
682912:  DTW     KJY     456           2012-01-23     2012-01-23        there           that         (Missing)
682913:  SET     FKG     565           2012-01-23     2012-01-23        there           that         (Missing)
682914:  QQQ     JKY     534           2012-01-23     2012-01-23        there           that         (Missing)
           attr_4   attr_5     attr_6  attr_7 attr_8 
     1: (Missing) (Missing) (Missing) starr      Over                   
     2: (Missing) (Missing) (Missing) starr      Over                   
     3: (Missing) (Missing) (Missing) starr      Over                   
     4: (Missing) (Missing) (Missing) starr      Under                   
     5: (Missing) (Missing) (Missing) starr      Under                  
    ---                                                                                   
682910: (Missing) (Missing) (Missing) starr      Over                   
682911:      King    Sponge    Square starr      Over                   
682912: (Missing) (Missing) (Missing) starr      Over                   
682913: (Missing) (Missing) (Missing) bob      Over                   
682914: (Missing) (Missing) (Missing) bob      Over
```

The unique key in the first data table is ID + Week (eg, every ID and Week combination only belong to a single group). In the second data frame, a given id + other id + yet_another_id pair can have multiple values for each of the attributes.

In the first data table, each ID has values for only some of the weeks. In the second data table, each id has values for many more weeks (though not all of the weeks). A given id will always have more values for weeks in the second data table than the first.

I'm trying to join the tables together with this command

```
      dt[dt2, on = .(id), 
                     allow.cartesian = TRUE][
                       , .(group = group[which.min(abs(i.week - week))],
                           id, other_id, yet_another_id,
                           week_group, 
                           attribute, other_attribute, yet_another_attribute,
                           attribute_again,
                           attr_4, attr_5, attr_6, attr_7, attr_8), 
                       .(id, i.week)][, .(week = i.week,
                                                 id, other_id, yet_another_id,
                           week_group, 
                           attribute, other_attribute, yet_another_attribute,
                           attribute_again,
                           attr_4, attr_5, attr_6, attr_7, attr_8)] %>%
             unique(.)
```

I'd like to join the ID in `dt` to the id in `dt2` where it's the closest week that is either equal to the week in `dt2` or the soonest week before that week. Then, I select all the columns and remove the dups.

But, I think I have a problem with the join because I'm getting this error:

> Warning message:
> In `[.data.table`(dt[dt2, on = .(id),  :
> Item 1 of j's result for group 8 is zero length. This will be filled with 2 NAs to match the longest column in this result. Later groups may have a similar problem but only the first is reported to save filling the warning buffer.

Comment: please provide some sample data which reproduces your problem, using `dput()`

Comment: `the R inferno, paragraph 9.8`:   A minimal, self-contained example allows readers to reproduce the problem easily. The easier you make it for your readers, the more likely you receive help. [...] It can not be emphasized enough that a message is putting yourself at the mercy of strangers. If someone has the wit and knowledge to answer your question, they probably have other things they would like to do. Making your message clear, concise and user-friendly gives you the best hope of at least one of those strangers diverting their attention away from their life towards your problem.

Comment: Reading the doc `?which.min`, you can see that it can return a length-0 result, explaining your warning about "zero length". Ex: `group = 1:3; w = which.min(NA); group[w]`. It is probably the case that after the join (and maybe even before?), you have some week or i.week with missing values, so there is no min distance between them.

Comment: That makes sense. When there is zero length, do you expect that the code will perform as expected? I'm wondering if it'll join to both of the weeks. I can test it on my system

Comment: just make your question reproducible by copy-paste and you will get up votes and useful answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some `id`s are in `dt2` that aren't in `dt`.

Try `dt2[!dt, on = 'id']` to see which ones.

You can also just add `nomatch = 0` to the initial join to discard them. I.e.

```
dt[dt2, on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = 0]
```

I've no idea if the rest of the code does what you want, though. Not without a reproducible example.